# Button should be only available after two events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few sidepanels and then a button which should be only available after someone has opened more than couple of sidepanels.
You can see in the fiddle I have a Click Me button which is currently available by default. But I want it to be available only when someone has opened the sidepanels more than couple of times.
Also the button should come from the above like the close button on sidepanels.

Could anyone please help thank you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/h9yfbden/5/)

HTML:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn-a abc"></i>
<div class="container">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn"></i>
</div>

<div class="place">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn-b abc"></i>
</div>
<div class="cd-panel from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container">
        Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-panel-a from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container color">
        Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cd-panel-b from-right"> 
            <header class="cd-panel-header">
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="cd-panel-container color-b">
        Content
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<button>
click me
</button>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
});


jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn-a
    if($('.cd-btn-a').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
       $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
       $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn-a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-a').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn
    if($('.cd-btn').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
       $('.cd-btn').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
       $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-a').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-a') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn-b').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel-b').toggleClass('is-visible');
    // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn
    if($('.cd-btn, .cd-btn-a').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
       $('.cd-btn, .cd-btn-a').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
       $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
    //close the lateral panel
    $('.cd-panel-b').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-a') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
            $('.cd-panel-b').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-btn-b').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Add a counter, and increase it every time a sidebar opens. See https://jsfiddle.net/h9yfbden/6/

Comment: @k97513 thank you, but what if someone closes the sidepanel using the close button instead of the icons.

Comment: Then do `opencount--`

Comment: @k97513 your solution works great for me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @k97513 I want to make your solution as the answer to this question. Could you please add the code to answers.

Comment: Sure give mea few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a variable that counts the number of sidebars open, such as

```
var openCounter = 0;
```

Then use `openCounter++` every time they open a sidebar, and `openCounter--` every time they close a sidebar. After they open it, check if they have say 3 sidebars open with

```
if (openCounter >= 3) {
  $('#yourButton').show();
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/h9yfbden/6/ for an example

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn-a abc"></i>
    <div class="container">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="place">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign cd-btn-b abc"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cd-panel from-right"> 
                <header class="cd-panel-header">
                    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
                </header>
                <div class="cd-panel-container">
            Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cd-panel-a from-right"> 
                <header class="cd-panel-header">
                    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
                </header>
                <div class="cd-panel-container color">
            Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cd-panel-b from-right"> 
                <header class="cd-panel-header">
                    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close"></a>
                </header>
                <div class="cd-panel-container color-b">
            Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button id='clickbtn' style="display:none;">
    click me
    </button>
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**script**

```
        var Counter =0; 
        $(".glyphicon-minus-sign, .glyphicon-plus-sign").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
            Counter++;
        });


        jQuery(function($){
            //open the lateral panel
            $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
          if(Counter>3){
            $("#clickbtn").show();
          }
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
            // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn-a
            if($('.cd-btn-a').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
               $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
               $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
             }
            });
            //close the lateral panel
            $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
                if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
                    $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
                    $('.cd-btn').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        jQuery(function($){
            //open the lateral panel
            $('.cd-btn-a').on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.cd-panel-a').toggleClass('is-visible');
            // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn
            if($('.cd-btn').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
               $('.cd-btn').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
               $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
             }
            });
            //close the lateral panel
            $('.cd-panel-a').on('click', function(event){
                if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-a') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
                    $('.cd-panel-a').removeClass('is-visible');
                    $('.cd-btn-a').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        jQuery(function($){
            //open the lateral panel
            $('.cd-btn-b').on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.cd-panel-b').toggleClass('is-visible');
            // CHECKING ICON OF .cd-btn
            if($('.cd-btn, .cd-btn-a').hasClass('glyphicon-minus-sign')) {
               $('.cd-btn, .cd-btn-a').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign');
               $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
             }
            });
            //close the lateral panel
            $('.cd-panel-b').on('click', function(event){
                if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-a') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
                    $('.cd-panel-b').removeClass('is-visible');
                    $('.cd-btn-b').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign glyphicon-plus-sign");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/h9yfbden/7/)

Answer (score -1):

Use a var as a counter, increment it each time a button is pressed and then use a simple if statement to check if you should enable the disabled element.

Something along the lines of :

```
<div>
  <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
  <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
  <button id="button3" disabled>Button 3</button>
</div>

<script>
var click_count=0;
$(button).click(function({
click_count++;
if(click_count>2){
  $("#button3").attr("disabled",false);
}}));
</script>
```

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1y5jpcxz/

Comment: I hadn't even noticed your comment. Perhaps if you'd posted an answer instead of a comment, I might have seen it.